# Getting warn messages for package scanning deprecation from pax-logging-api

Tags: log4j2

We are currently using pax-logging version 2.1.0 currently and trying to migrate to the latest 2.2.7 version.

When trying to start the server I'm getting the following warning multiple times.

```
org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api [log4j2] WARN : The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
```

Further debugging the issue I identified that this is yielding from the line [1] in log4j-core version 2.22.1. This seems to be due to the following packages added from the PluginManager the pax-logging-log4j2 component [2].

Therefore, even there are no packages from our side, the warning messages are logged. Is there a way to work around this or am I missing something?

[1] https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/rel/2.22.1/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/plugins/util/PluginManager.java#L128

[2] https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/logging-2.2.7/pax-logging-log4j2/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/log4j2/internal/PaxLoggingServiceImpl.java#L79

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems like this is due to the use of the deprecated method `PluginManager.addPackage` as per the log4j [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/plugins.html).